# Deploying Elixir App to Google Cloud via Docker

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get my docker image deployed to Google Cloud and I'm running into some problems. Everything works locally. I run

```
docker run -it -p 4000:4000 myimage
```

And everything works when I go to `localhost:4000`. However, when I try to deploy to Google Cloud with the command

```
gcloud app deploy --version=1 app.yaml
```

The deployment runs smoothly but when I navigate to my site, I get a 503 error:

## Error: Server Error

### The service you requested is not available yet.

### Please try again in 30 seconds.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you use google app engine for deploying elixir(& other apps) app container,

you should use 8080 port & expose 8080 port.

thanks